# How do I turn data from a text file into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My objective here is to open the dog file, convert it into a list, and then let the user enter a type of dog and if it matches a dog name in the list, say it's  correct.

```
dog_file = open("Dogs.txt", "r")
dogs = dog_file.readlines()
print(dogs)
data = input("Enter a name: ")
if data == dogs:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Sorry that didn't work")
```

Comment: `if data == dogs` won't work because you're testing for equality against a list. Maybe `if data in dogs`

Comment: You are almost there. Just change the `if` check. `if data+'\n' in dogs:`

Answer (score 3):

`dogs` is a list of strings while `data` is a single string. You want to check if `data` **is contained** in `dogs` using the `in` operator:

```
if data in dogs:
    # do sth
```

Comment: the thing is when I type an answer, I get the result of the else statement.

Comment: maybe there are some whitespace characters like \n or \r at the end of each line, try: `dogs = [dog.strip() for dog in dog_file.readlines()]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the .txt into an array (convert to list), try this:

```
with open("Dogs.txt", "r") as ins:
    dogarray = []
    for line in ins:
        line = line.strip()
        dogarray.append(line)
    print (dogarray)
```

This writes it into an array and uses the `.strip` function to remove the unwanted `\n` after every new line. All you need to do now is read from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dog_file = open("Dogs.txt", "r")
dogs = dog_file.readlines()
# you want to strip away the spaces and new line characters
content = [x.strip() for x in dogs]
data = input("Enter a name: ")
# since dogs here is a list
if data in dogs:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("Sorry that didn't work")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dog_list = []
for dog in dogs:
    dog_list.append(dog)
```

This will append every line of the file into a list. Now to check if there is a dog in the list try:

```
dog_type = input("Enter a dog: ")
if dog_type in dog_list":
    print("Success")
```